# Non-dairy creamer, dry

Tags: substitutions

Is there a substitute for powdered non-dairy creamer that does not have transfat or hydrogenated fat? I want to make dry hot chocolate mix.

Answer (score 2):

I usually see powdered milk used rather than non-dairy creamer, as in [this recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/hot-cocoa-recipe/index.html); [This source](http://www.foodfacts.com/allergies/Controversial-Ingredients/Trans-Fat/3/73) seems to say it has less or no trans fat.

Comment: You can get nonfat dry milk (sometimes labeled "skim"), which definitely doesn't have trans fat or hydrogenated fat.